# How many numbers from $1$ to $N$ are not divisible by any of these given set of primes $p_1, p_2, ... , p_k$?

Tags: number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

How many numbers from $1$ to $n$ are there such that a given a set of primes ${p_1, p_2,\ldots,p_k}$ don't divide those numbers from $1$ to $n$?

Take an example: Find how many numbers from $1$ to $5,000,000$ (suppose) are not divisible by any of $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19$? 
In the question, the set of primes is some $p_1, p_2, \ldots , p_k$ and not necessarily these $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19$.

What I have thought is pretty vague for bigger cases as for the example I mentioned.. I thought to do by separating out the ${p_i}$ divisible terms and then add ${p_i p_j}$ divisible terms.. and like that. I am not stating much of my idea as it's just the normal **Principle of Exclusion-Inclusion** based idea..

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion approach can give some nontrivial bounds (though not very good ones) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_sieve

Comment: Hmm, but still it's pathetic to solve. Anyway, can someone at least give an approximate to the example problem I have just given? I can develop some idea

Comment: I believe the best you can do for deriving an exact formula is inclusion-exclusion. A simpler closed form solution seems unlikely.

Comment: Can you tell me by PIE then? Mine is getting bigger and bigger..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $N$ is a multiple of all the listed primes, the count you want is exactly
$$ N \cdot \frac{1}{2}   \cdot \frac{2}{3}  \cdot \frac{4}{5}  \cdot \frac{6}{7}  \cdot \frac{10}{11}  \cdot \frac{12}{13}  \cdot \frac{16}{17}  \cdot \frac{18}{19}   $$
If your $N$ is not such a multiple, the rational number obtained will just be very close to the correct figure.

Recommend the book by Mark Kac on statistical independence.

In the very special case where $N = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k,$ with the listed primes $p_i$ **distinct**, then the numbers up to $N$ that are not divisible by any prime in the list are simply those that are relativley prime to $N,$ and their count is
$$ \phi(N) = (p_1 -1)(p_2 - 1)\cdots (p_k-1). $$ For example
$$ N = 21. $$
The numbers relatively prime to $21,$ from $1$ to $21,$ but including $1,$ are
$$ 1,2,4,5,8,10,11,13,16,17,19,20. $$
These are also the numbers up to $21$ that are not divisible by $3$ or $7.$ There are twelve of them. $(3-1)(7-1) = 2 \cdot 6 = 12.$

Comment: I think there won't be two 1/2's to be multiplied. And can you explain your reasoning in short? Or is it there in the book?

Comment: @Mathbg I fixed that a couple of minutes ago. Anyway, suggest  testing this for just a few primes and $N$ small enough to run on computer, say.

Comment: @Mathbg not a coincidence: when $N$ is precisely the product of the primes in the list, the number you want is Euler's totient $\phi(N)$